# Массив объектов отвечающий двум разным интерфейсам

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Всем привет. Вопрос про тайпскрипт)
Смотрите есть массив объектов. Отвечает двум интерфейсам. Дальше я хочу фильтровать по типу объекта и вызывать специфичные методы. Тайпскрипт ругается. Мол того может попасться в отфильтрованном массиве элемент без такого метода.
Как здесь лучше поступить?

[Вот пример в песочнице.](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-jackson-l2u4j?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Встречал такую штуку:

```
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
   return (<Fish>pet).swim !== undefined;
}

if (isFish(pet)) pet.swim();
```

#### Доки:

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards
- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards

Comment: ещё вот так можно https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator